# Two-tape DFA checking for |u| = 2|v|

Tags: turing-machines, automata, finite-automata

The question for my homework is to create a two-tape DFA for accepting two string such that u is 2x the size of v.

I am just confused on where to go with this, i understand this in a base sense but i can't figure out how i would find if it is 2x V after getting beyond V

Comment: Are you sure it is two-tape DFA? (afaik it is a bit exotic) Is it 6-tuple defined and denoted 2TFA? (Also 2TFA cannot exacly count, so maybe some constraint is missing?) Or did you mean multi-tape Turing machine with two tapes? What are your thoughts so far?

Comment: deterministic two-tape finite automaton as said by book in the example i am looking at

Comment: Could you give a name of that book?

Comment: Theory of Computing, A gentle Introduction By Efim Kinber, Carl Smith

Comment: Basically it reads the first character on the first line and then goes to the specific state and then reads the first character on the 2nd string. then 2nd character first string to 2nd character 2nd string so on and so forth up until you get to the end of a string which is denoted by #.

it will continue this until you finish both strings.